# Qt mediaplayer C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to play music when the user is clicking a key. But music plays only once when I click first time. Help please.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>


class Rect : public QGraphicsRectItem
{
public:
    Rect()
    {
        player = new QMediaPlayer();
        output = new QAudioOutput();
        player->setAudioOutput(output);
        output->setVolume(50);
        player->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/gun.mp3"));
        player->play();
    }
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev)
    {
        player->play();
    }

private:
    QMediaPlayer* player;
    QAudioOutput* output;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QGraphicsScene* scene= new QGraphicsScene();
    Rect* rect = new Rect();
    rect->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    rect->setFocus();
    rect->setRect(0, 0, 300, 400);
    scene->addItem(rect);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
    view->show();



    return a.exec();

    delete view;
    delete scene;
    delete rect;
}
```

........................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Qt has an official media player example. [link](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimediawidgets/player?h=5.15)

Note: the load of the media is asynchronous. play/stop/pause will control the position of the stream so you can replay it by controlling it. Please check the example project.